# Install semantic-ui in laravel project 5.2

Tags: laravel, semantic-ui

How i install semantic in laravel project?

I try install `npm install semantic-ui --save` and `gulp build` but doesn't work.

Comment: You can't install javascript packages in php...

Comment: So, i can´t use semantic-ui in laravel?

Comment: Well, no, not in Laravel directly, although if you're building a web app you can obviously use any javascript you want to. But Laravel itself is php.

Comment: I'm building a web app, how i add semantic to my project?

Comment: Start by generating the necessary javascript, then call it from your views. Here's a good starting point: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir

Comment: Thank you for your answers!